# Why i can't change charset?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

Why I can't change charset?

I'm using mssql.

```
...
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:$data_source", $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
$dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
...
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo mb_detect_encoding($row['Name1']);
  print $row['Name1'] . "\t";
}
```

And I get somthing like that: `ASCII????????    ASCII????????   ASCII?????????`

Comment: I use dblib unsted odbc and my problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your syntax is wrong.

Running `SET NAMES utf8` in SQL Server Management Studio directly returns:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 7, Line 1
'NAMES' is not a recognized SET option.
```

And running `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` returns:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
```